# Is there a close-up of a boot or a wheel in Titanic?

Tags: directors, titanic

I've read somewhere that James Cameron almost always includes a close-up of a boot or of a wheel (usually crushing something) in all his movies. But is there such a close-up in *Titanic*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a boot as such but it does seem that Cameron has something about feet or establishing shots starting from ground level.

There are a number of shots in *Titanic* which start with feet/footwear.

This YouTube video covers a lot of these shots with the *Titanic* ones at 3.10